# jQuery Mobile, List views Thumbnails size

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm integrating jQuery Mobile with List views Thumbnails, but it resizes my images on fly to fixed width. Changing .ui-li-thumb width doesn't help. How to make my thumbs wider?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this and include ", .ui-li-icon"!

```
.ui-li-thumb, .ui-li-icon {
    left: 1px;
    max-height: 60px; 
    max-width: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

This effects the thumbnail size to 60*60px .. working in my case with every size.

If this does not work, provide some of your code to see whats wrong (HTML, JS, CSS).

Answer (score 2):

I was wanting to make the thumbnails in the listview smaller. This is how I did it with `jQuery Mobile` version `1.4.2`:

```
.ui-listview .ui-li-has-thumb > img:first-child,
.ui-listview .ui-li-has-thumb > .ui-btn > img:first-child,
.ui-listview .ui-li-has-thumb .ui-li-thumb {
    left: 1px;
    top: 1px;
    max-height: 40px;
    max-width: 40px;
}
.ui-listview > .ui-li-has-thumb > .ui-btn,
.ui-listview > .ui-li-static.ui-li-has-thumb {
    min-height: 0;
    padding: .7em 1em .7em 55px;
}
```

The top, left and bottom padding that I define above is just to put these padding values back to the default values for `ui-btn`. The image is positioned absolutely in the listview item, so if you want to make the image bigger then you must compensate for that by increasing the `min-height` css property shown above.

Comment: This deserves more +1's!

Comment: Thanks, James111. Glad that it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

For me this solution works ok in the list. It adjust also padding of the internal text from the thumb.

```
.ui-listview .ui-li-icon{
    max-height: 32px; 
    max-width: 32px;
}
.ui-li-static.ui-li-has-icon{
    padding-left:50px;
}
```

It is done for the case when you have .ui-li-icon class applied to the image